# Global.asax - FxCop Warning Conflict CA1811 vs CA2109

Tags: asp.net, performance, security, global-asax, fxcop

I'm working on an ASP.NET project.  The projected of course has a Global.asax file.  Inside of the Global.asax.cs file, it contains each of the following methods, which [with the exception of `Application_Start`] aren't really empty, but no need for the actual implementation:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){ }
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){ }
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e){ }
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){ }
```

I have slowly been enabling each of the FxCop rules Visual Studio 2008 has to offer and recently came across a conflict pertaining to the above methods.  The first error I came across is CA2109

```
CA2109 : Microsoft.Security : Consider making 'Global.Application_Error(object, EventArgs)' not externally visible.
```

This error is displayed for each method.  Since I do not manually call any of these methods, I can remove this warning by making each of the methods `private`.  After doing so, and re-running the Code Analysis, I receive error CA1811:

```
CA1811 : Microsoft.Performance : 'Global.Application_Error(object, EventArgs)' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.
```

My question to all of you out there in the Stack Overflow community world is this:  Which warning should I listen to and which warning should I suppress?  Is there a way to satisfy both warnings?

Am I correct in assuming Security trumps all and thus I should listen to CA2109 and suppress CA1811?

Answer (score 2):

CA1811 is actually "Avoid uncalled private code". This would imply FXCop thinks they're not being called, as there's no explicit event bindings. Auto Event Wire Up means they are called & this rule can be suppressed, or you could explicitly handle the events which would have the same effect.

"CA2109: Review visible event handlers" kinda says the same thing. It knows they're event handlers, but says why do they need to be visible outside the class?

The rules aren't really contradictory, they're just not very clear on what they're suggesting to you.